# PHP SCRIPT Should Upload images too along with its description

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Following is my script which i want to use to update status on my facebook fanpage but its not working in a way that the uploaded image can't be viewed in the gallery of facebook fanpage kindly see this link ( http://radiations3.com/damn.jpg ) its a detailed screenshot of what exactly is happening by my script and what am i trying to do/want from my script. Kindly let me know what is wrong with my script and what should i do instead?

```
 <?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = "332267477347";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true,
 'fileUpload' => true,

));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  


$user = $facebook->getUser();
//echo $user;

if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'photo_upload,user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}");
 exit;
}
else {
$accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
echo "i am connected";
}
  $valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');


//to get the page access token to post as a page
foreach($accounts_list['data'] as $account){
      if($account['id'] == 194458563914948){      // my page id =123456789
        $access_token = $account['access_token'];
        echo "<p>Page -- Access Token: $access_token</p>";
        }
    }

//posting to the page wall

if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES))
{  
$folder = "pak/".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
$fold = 'http://snowdrop.com.pk/fb/'.$folder;
echo $fold."<br>";
if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $folder) )
{
#Upload photo here
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
$attachment = array('message' => $_POST['textfield'],
                             'picture' => $fold,
                                'access_token' => $access_token,


                );
$status = $facebook->api("/194458563914948/feed", 'post', $attachment);

echo $status;
var_dump($status);

 }
 else{
    echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';

}
}
?>
<body>
 <!-- Form for uploading the photo -->
 <div class="main">
  <p>Select a photo to upload on Facebook Fan Page</p>
  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Select the image: <input type="file" name="pic" />
    <br />
    <label>Description
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p><input class="post_but" type="submit" value="Upload to my album" /></p>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

[image: Detailed image of what my script is doing and what i want instead]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the effect you are looking for you need to upload to an album id. In the code below just add the album id you wish to upload to.

---

```
$status = $facebook->api("/Album_ID/photos", 'post', $attachment);
```

---

```
<?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = "332267477347";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true,
 'fileUpload' => true,

));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  


$user = $facebook->getUser();
//echo $user;

if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'photo_upload,user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}");
 exit;
}
else {
$accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
echo "i am connected";
}
  $valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');


//to get the page access token to post as a page
foreach($accounts_list['data'] as $account){
      if($account['id'] == 194458563914948){      // my page id =123456789
        $access_token = $account['access_token'];
        echo "<p>Page -- Access Token: $access_token</p>";
        }
    }

//posting to the page wall

if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES))
{  
$folder = "pak/".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
$fold = 'http://snowdrop.com.pk/fb/'.$folder;
echo $fold."<br>";
if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $folder) )
{
#Upload photo here
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
$attachment = array('message' => $_POST['textfield'],
                             'source' => $fold,
                                'access_token' => $access_token,


                );
$status = $facebook->api("/Album_ID/photos", 'post', $attachment);

echo $status;
var_dump($status);

 }
 else{
    echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';

}
}
?>
<body>
 <!-- Form for uploading the photo -->
 <div class="main">
  <p>Select a photo to upload on Facebook Fan Page</p>
  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Select the image: <input type="file" name="pic" />
    <br />
    <label>Description
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p><input class="post_but" type="submit" value="Upload to my album" /></p>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How can i  issue an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/photos with the publish_stream and manage_pages permissions . I did this though if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'photo_upload,user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}");
 exit;
}

Comment: Issue is being resolved now there was a problem with this line of code 'source' => '@' . $img, and when i changed it to 'source' => '@' . realpath($folder), then the code worked like a charm....